# '80s/'90s sci-fi film about aliens that use telepathy to send a code involving 1s, 0s and Xs to humans

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

In the early '90s a film came on TV where humans would suddenly be interrupted whatever they were doing, and start either saying aloud or writing 1s, 0s and Xs. In one scene a teacher was writing on her chalkboard, went into a sudden trance and started scribbling 110X0X00X... it got to the attention of scientists who were seeing more and more cases of this happening.

Eventually one of the women scientists asked for all the cases of 10Xs to be printed off. Using that old perforated paper their printer started whirling it off and they quickly found themselves overwhelmed with paper. The woman then says to paste it on the walls of the room. Once done, she realizes its a code, and begins to draw connecting lines between the numbers, like a dot to dot. The final picture is of an alien and 2 naked humans, one male one female.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I believe this is a *The Outer Limits* episode, titled "[The Message](https://theouterlimits.fandom.com/wiki/The_Message)" (1995).

> Jennifer Winter (Marlee Matlin), deaf since birth, has had a revolutionary implant placed in her ear, to help her hear for the first time. The device doesn't help her to hear normal conversation and sounds, but she does hear something, and no one believes her.
>
> While on a routine visit to the hospital to check on the implant, Jennifer befriends the janitor, Robert (Larry Drake) who empathizes with her.
>
> **Suddenly, Jennifer is plagued by nightmares and searing pain in her head, all at 3:10 in the morning or afternoon. Once the pain starts she begins furiously writing in binary code, but with ×'s as well.**
>
> Robert suggests that perhaps the binary coded 0s and 1s might be able to be translated. As a former astrophysicist who had a mental break which forced him to work as a janitor, Robert enters the code into his computer to try to translate it.
>
> Meanwhile, Jennifer's husband Sam, concerned for his wife and their young baby, is convinced that Jennifer is going crazy. But as the sounds and dreams become more pronounced Jennifer and Robert are determined to break the code.
>
> **What they discover is an alien force, trying to communicate a cry for help through Jennifer's implant. The aliens are in a ship hurtling toward the sun and they need help from Earth to save their ship. The message sent was really instructions for a high energy laser designed to push the ship out of a terminal path. They build and activate it just in time to see the ship pushed away from the sun and towards safety while they watch.**

The episode does involve a scene where the female protagonist (who is deaf and mute) asks for the code to be printed out on sheets of paper and pinned to a wall. She then uses a black marker to draw a line through the Xs, which produces a picture of an alien standing next to a naked human male and female.

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for your answer. In 6 minutes you have solved a mystery I've had for 20+ years. No wonder if couldn't find the film! The image is clear as day in my mind, and this is 100% what I was trying to find. Thank you so much

Comment: "They build and activate it just in time to see the ship pushed away from the sun and towards safety while they watch." That's a tremendous weapon, you could cook a whole continent with it during breakfast.

Comment: Worth noting that the naked-people image is from the [Pioneer plaque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pioneer_plaque), a message sent on the 2 Pioneer probes.  Obviously the alien has been added for the show.

Comment: As a tween when the Pioneers were launched, I think it was one of my first times seeing a picture of a naked woman.